# Cannot select a few columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

file_list = [ i.path for i in dbutils.fs.ls("/location/01/01/01/01/") ]

df = spark.read.json(file_list)

test_df = df.select(F.col('card_1.card_type'))

test_df.show()
```

I get this error message

```
Column 'card_1.card_type' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [card_1.card_type, card_1.name, ... ]
```

Can anyone please tell how to resolve this?

Comment: can you add `df.printSchema()` pls?

Comment: yes, I can see the column. Also as you can see in the spark error message, the column is prersent there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding backquote ` will fix your issue :

```py
test_df = df.select(F.col('`card_1.card_type`'))
```